# React-Native / Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Getting this error in the project, building a React Native project with Expo. I think there is a problem with @react-navigation/native dependencies, but my research didn't give me a solution. I tried many things to solve it, but it didn't work:

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

**package.json:**

```
{
"name": "travelguide",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@firebase/app": "^0.9.3",
"@firebase/auth": "^0.21.3",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.1",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"eas-cli": "^3.7.2",
"expo": "\~48.0.4",
"expo-dev-client": "\~2.1.4",
"expo-status-bar": "\~1.4.4",
"firebase": "^9.17.1",
"link": "^1.5.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.71.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.20.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

**App.js:**

```
import { StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import "expo-dev-client";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/LoginScreen";
import BottomNavigation from "./src/components/BottomNavigation";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="BottomNavigation"
          component={BottomNavigation}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[The screenshot of the Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1DxD.png)

Thanks in advance...